# Could someone please help with some questions related to using Magento 1 database backup functionality?

Tags: database, backup, magento-1.14

I want to get a Magento 1 backup using Magento's backup functionality. (Reference:https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/server-backup-create.html)

I'm are running Magento ver. 1.14.0.1

1. I would like to get the menu option for backups enabled under
   System->Tools->Backups as this option is not currently available.
   How can this be done?
2. Would taking a backup in this way, have a significant server performance impact considering there are a large number of records?
3. Will this include custom field data or just the default Magento fields?
4. Could this backup be used for a migrating date to M2 using the migration tool in Magento 2?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow the steps given [here](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-back-up-your-magento-1-store.html) to create automatic scheduled backup. You can decide to backup Code, Database, Media files or all together. (Make sure cron is enabled for your site)
2. Yes it does impacts the performance, since cronjob is executed to backup your code/media/database which constantly queries on system. But I don't think the impact is much.
3. If you do a database backup, everything in the database get backed up. All your custom & default Magento fields as well.
4. Yes you can use this to migrate you database as well as code to M2.

Hope it finds helpful.

Comment: Thank you Abdul! This is very helpful.

Comment: Welcome @AbeM, if you find this post helpful please accept the answer so  that will be helpful for other newbies.